# How can I add event Listener to google sheets link in chrome extension's content script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-sheets, google-docs

I'm developing a chrome extension to open links from different columns to their assigned tab.
Using *Google apps script API* to create a context of the sheet inside the chrome extension. But *Google apps script API* is a long path and I can't avoid opening and closing of tabs on clicking link form sheet.

Now I want to add an event listener for click on sheet *link/tooltip link.*
I am Already using a content script to inject a  panel in the sheet.

**Here is code from (content script).** related to the link.

```
(function() {
  let sheetLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.waffle-hyperlink-tooltip-link');
  for (let i = 0; i < link.length; i++) {
    sheetLinks[i].addEventListener("click", sendHref);
  }

  function sendHref(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('link was clicked')
  }
})()
```

By hovering over google sheet link we can click a link in a tooltip.
there I want to prevent-default and send Href by chrome message to background script.and from there I can update tabs URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the dom element is changing, when you listen here, the dom element will not be useful after the next update.

The solution is to use DOMSubtreeModified.

Below is my solution:

```
const stopURL = 'javascript:void(0)';
document.querySelector('#docs-editor-container').addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', event => {
  const aTags = event.path.filter(dom => dom.nodeName === 'A' && dom.className === 'waffle-hyperlink-tooltip-link');

  if (aTags.length === 0) return;

  aTags.forEach(a => {
    const oldHref = a.href;
    if (oldHref === stopURL) return;
    a.href = stopURL;
    console.log(oldHref);
  })
})
```

Now you can send oldHref to your extension and then operate from the extension.

It should be noted that this will trigger a CSP error, but it doesn't matter, this error will not affect the entire page and your extension.

As shown:

[image]

Comment: It's promising, but its firing with or without clicking. can we make it for the only click and hide the tooltip...

Comment: Listening to a single click doesn't seem to work, because dom is always changing. If you only listen once, the latest dom element will overwrite the old one. That monitoring is useless. Hide the tooltip, I don't understand this, what does it mean?